# how to close a class into another file

Tags: php, class

i have a very big single class file ,and i want to break this too big class and distribute it's code in  a multiple files,but **without** using the extend method,as i want to use only the same object for this class
ex:

file a:

```
class name {

    public function admin_logout(){

    if(isset($_SESSION['wcddl_admin'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['wcddl_admin']);
            session_destroy();
            header("Location:index.php");
  }

}
```

file b:

```
include("a.php");

 }
```

i tried something like that,but didn't work

anyidea?

Comment: Why do you want to this?  It doesn't matter if the file is big - if the methods in it _should_ be logically grouped in a class, keep them all together.

Comment: It's usually never a good idea to span classes across multiple files, just by the nature of how classes work.  What if Method A calls Method B that calls Method C, but Method B is in Class File 2 and Method C is in class file 3.  If your class is too big try looking at ways to refactor template code out of it into helper classes.

Comment: it sounds like you're writing One Class to Rule them All. You might consider instead writing a Handler class that users interact with and a bunch of other classes that the Handler uses to do things.

Comment: michael,i want to seperate some snippet of this class to be a premium snippet for using for premium users,
------
mike,sure i knew isn't agood method,am just guess if there is alternative method to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't natively split a class across files in php.  I suppose you could do something fancy like build a file dynamically and then load it but that would be a pain.

With respect to your premium class, you could make a base class for normal users and then extend it into a premium class.  But more than likely you are probably trying to put too much in one class.

You might want to start another question and describe the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a php file with invalid syntax.
But you can include a file for each method.

```
class name {
    public function admin_logout(){
        include('methods/admin_logout.php');
    }
    public function mymethod(){
        include('methods/mymethod.php');
    }
}
```

Or you can build a class with magic method __call

```
class name {
    public function __call($name, $arguments){
        include('methods/'.$name.'.php');
    }
}
```

However if you are forced to do something like that, maybe you should change approach of your project.